# Lipschitz Continuity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a quick question on how to interpret Lipschitz Continuity rather than normal continuity. What is the exact difference between the two, because I can't really find one. And is it more general than normal continuity or is it a more strict kind of continuity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lipschitz continuity implies ordinary continuity, so it's a more strict kind. It places an upper bound on how step any secant of the function graph can be, so you may think of it as a more relaxed version of differentiability (with a bounded derivative). In fact, [Rademacher's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher%27s_theorem) states that a Lipschitz continuous function is differentiable almost everywhere (and don't worry if you don't know what “almost everywhere” means – the point is that it is *mostly* differentiable).

For examples of continuous functions that aren't Lipschitz continuous, look no further than $f(x)=x^{1/3}$. (Hint: Compare $f(x)-f(0)=x^{1/3}$ with $x-0=x$ for $0<x\ll 1$.)

Comment: So, if I get it right, your example is way too steep when you go very close to zero, so that no constant can be found to make it Lipschitz continuous? (Using the definition |f(x,y) - f(x,z)| \leq K *|y - z| for some constant K > 0 that I have). And I guess your 'almost everywhere' refers to singularities in the differential equations?

Comment: First part, yes. Second part, no. “Almost everywhere” is a measure theoretic concept, important in integration theory.

Comment: Ok, way out of my league, thank you very much, this actually helped me in more ways than just the interpretation of the continuity!